# generating Multiple output file from mapper in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, chain, multipleoutputs, mappers

I am working on producing two output files from mapper.I am using Multipleoutput api for producing two outputs.I am not sure ,if it is the correct way to do it .here is my code..
please go through this and give me your suggestions..when i run the code i am getting **Error: java.lang.NullPointerException**..

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class Export_Column_Mapping 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String Output_filetype = args[2];
        String Input_column_number = args[3];
        String Output_column_number = args[4];


        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.setStrings("output_filetype",Output_filetype);
        conf.setStrings("Input_column_number",Input_column_number);
        conf.setStrings("Output_column_number",Output_column_number);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Export_Column_Mapping");
        job.setJarByClass(Export_Column_Mapping.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }


    public static class Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
    {   
        private MultipleOutputs<Text, LongWritable> mos ;

        public void setup(TaskInputOutputContext<?, ?, Text, LongWritable> context) {
            mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, LongWritable>(context);
        }

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            String str_Output_filetype = context.getConfiguration().get("output_filetype"); 

            String str_Input_column_number = context.getConfiguration().get("Input_column_number");
            String[] input_columns_number = str_Input_column_number.split(",");

            String str_Output_column_number= context.getConfiguration().get("Output_column_number");    
            String[] output_columns_number = str_Output_column_number.split(",");

            String str_line = value.toString();
            String[] input_column_array = str_line.split(",");
            String[] Detail_output_column_array = new String[27];
            String[] Shop_output_column_array = new String[8];
            String details_output = null ;
            String Shop_output = null;
        try
        {

            for(int i = 0;i<=input_column_array.length+1; i++)
            {
                int int_outputcolumn = Integer.parseInt(output_columns_number[i]);
                int int_inputcolumn = Integer.parseInt(input_columns_number[i]);

                if((int_inputcolumn != 0) && (int_outputcolumn != 0) && output_columns_number.length == input_columns_number.length){

                    Detail_output_column_array[int_outputcolumn-1] = input_column_array[int_inputcolumn-1];
                    Shop_output_column_array[0] = Detail_output_column_array[0];
                    Shop_output_column_array[1] = Detail_output_column_array[1];
                    Shop_output_column_array[2] = Detail_output_column_array[2];
                    Shop_output_column_array[3] = Detail_output_column_array[3];
                    Shop_output_column_array[4] = Detail_output_column_array[14];


                    if(details_output != null)
                    {
                        details_output = details_output+"       "+ Detail_output_column_array[int_outputcolumn-1];
                        Shop_output = Shop_output+"     "+ Shop_output_column_array[int_outputcolumn-1];

                    }else
                    {
                        details_output = Detail_output_column_array[int_outputcolumn-1];
                        Shop_output =  Shop_output_column_array[int_outputcolumn-1];

                    }
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
            mos.write("Details File", null, details_output);
            mos.write("Shop File", null, Shop_output);

    }
}
}
```

*here is the log..*

> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.nielsen.grfe.Export_Column_Mapping$Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper.map(Export_Column_Mapping.java:113)
>           at com.nielsen.grfe.Export_Column_Mapping$Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper.map(Export_Column_Mapping.java:1)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your MultipleOutputs is as follows:

```
private MultipleOutputs<Text, LongWritable> mos ;
```

While write the following is the code:-

```
mos.write("Details File", null, details_output);
mos.write("Shop File", null, Shop_output);
```

It should be like

```
mos.write(your key in definition, your value in definition, output directory name as string)
```

Change your definition, write and corresponding things as below:

```
private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> mos ;
mos.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(details_output),"Details File");
mos.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(Shop_output),"Shop File");
 public static class Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,NullWritable,Text>
{   
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
```

Also include the clean up code:

```
protected void cleanup(Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
multipleOutputs.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment,But still i get null pointer exception.
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nielsen.grfe.Export_Column_Mapping$Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper.map(Export_Column_Mapping.java:113)
        at com.nielsen.grfe.Export_Column_Mapping$Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper.map(Export_Column_Mapping.java:1)

Comment: Yeah after seperating i get- The public type Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper must be defined in its own file ..error in the mapper class

Comment: **The public type Export_Column_Mapping_Mapper must be defined in its own file**--this is the error

Comment: Separate means asked you create a new mapper class...Hope you have not separated in the same file with braces....